# Postgres invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Token "%" is invalid

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, jsonb

I'm trying to check if some text contains the concatenation of a text and a value from an array in Postgres, something like:

```
SELECT true from jsonb_array_elements('["a", "b"]'::jsonb) as ids 
WHERE 'bar/foo/item/b' LIKE '%item/' || ids->>'id' || '%'
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Token "%" is invalid. Position: 95 Where: JSON data, line 1: %...
```

How can I make use of the values of the array, concatenate them with the text and check the `LIKE` expression?

I have tried several ideas of explicitly adding a cast like `::jsonb`, but no luck so far.

Comment: 'bar/foo/item/b' LIKE '%item/' ||  NULLIF('', ids->>'id') || '%'

Comment: @Rhim that actually remove the error, but it's not working, the values are always getting empty and the expression is evaluating to true

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the `||` and `->>` operators have the same [precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE-TABLE) and are left associative, so the expression is interpreted as

```
(('%item/' || ids) ->>'id') || '%'
```

You'd have to add parentheses:

```
'%item/' || (ids->>'id') || '%'
```

Comment: I tried that solution, but it's giving empty result: `SELECT true from jsonb_array_elements('["a", "b"]'::jsonb) as ids WHERE 'bar/foo/item/b' LIKE '%item/' || (ids->>'id') || '%'`

Comment: Yes, but that was the cause for the error message. There was probably some other problem with your query. But you have a solution now anyway.

Comment: You are right, thanks for your help, I'm new to Postgres. I still don't understand why using jsonb_array_elements_text it does concatenate the values and using jsonb_array_elements don't. The correct answer to my question I think is yours, I'm just trying to understand why it does not work as I expect, so you can edit it to accept it :).

Comment: As I see in the docs jsonb_array_elements: Expands a JSON array to a set of JSON values and jsonb_array_elements_text: Expands a JSON array to a set of text values, it have sense that text values should be used to concatenate with other text values and probably the json values from jsonb_array_elements should be casted or converted to text before used.

Comment: Shouldn't matter, because `json` will implicitly be cast to `text` upon concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this working, this is the result:

```
SELECT true from jsonb_array_elements_text('["a", "c"]'::jsonb) as ids 
WHERE 'bar/foo/item/b' LIKE '%item/' || ids.value || '%'
```

The key changes were to use `jsonb_array_elements_text` instead of `jsonb_array_elements` and `ids.value` instead of `ids->>'id'`